# The UDF is completely dead when the range has 50,000 rows for calculation

Tags: excel, vba

I created a UDF below which is expected to work nicely. The idea is to calculated weighted average for a variable (cases need to meet the criteria). But when the range contains 50,000 rows (e.g. A1:A50000), this macro is just dead. Excel just keeps running for hours after hours without responding. I thought array in VBA is quick enough to handle 50,000 rows. I am wondering if there is a better way to do calculation when there are so many rows used.

```
Function SurpAvg(code As String, per As String, var As String, _
                                        dt1 As Range, dt2 As Range)

Dim weight As Variant, fperiod As Variant, ftype As Variant, ann As Variant, surpx As Variant
Dim startdt As Date, enddt As Date
Dim pctL As Double, pctH As Double, surpL As Double, surpH As Double
Dim i As Long, j As Long, a() As Variant, b() As Variant, total As Double, totalWT As Double

ThisWorkbook.Activate

With Application
    weight = .Transpose(Range(code).Value)
    fperiod = .Transpose(Range("FY").Value)
    ftype = .Transpose(Range("FT").Value)
    ann = .Transpose(Range("ann").Value)
    surpx = .Transpose(Range("surpx").Value)
End With

startdt = dt1.Value
enddt = dt2.Value
pctL = Range("PctL")
pctH = Range("PctH")
surpL = -Range("MaxSurp")
surpH = Range("MaxSurp")

i = -1
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
For j = LBound(surpx) To UBound(surpx)
    If ftype(j) = var And ann(j) > startdt And ann(j) <= enddt And _
       IsNumeric(1 / weight(j)) And IsNumeric(1 / surpx(j)) And _
       surpx(j) > surpL And surpx(j) < surpH Then

        If InStr(fperiod(j), per) Then
            i = i + 1
            ReDim Preserve a(i) As Variant
            ReDim Preserve b(i) As Variant
            a(i) = surpx(j)
            b(i) = weight(j)
        End If
    End If
NextJ:
Next j
ErrorHandler:
If Err Then Resume NextJ

surpL = WorksheetFunction.Percentile(a, pctL)
surpH = WorksheetFunction.Percentile(a, pctH)

total = 0: totalWT = 0
For j = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    totalWT = totalWT + b(j)
    If a(j) < surpL Then
        total = total + surpL * b(j)
    ElseIf a(j) > surpH Then
        total = total + surpH * b(j)
    Else
        total = total + a(j) * b(j)
    End If
Next j
SurpAvg = total / totalWT
End Function
```

Comment: Redim Preserve will use a lot of overhead.  Set the size of the arrays prior.  Maybe using COUNTIF() to find how many have `per` in them and set the size of the array to that.

Comment: Where is your formula spending its time?  Have you tried adding some debug.print statements with a smaller dataset to see there the most time is going?  eg in the first loop, or the second?  Scotts comment on ReDim Preserve is worth looking at: set your arrays to the max possible size and then cut them down to the used size after the first loop .

Comment: Also note that execution is falling-through into the error-handling subroutine, which makes for rather spaghettish code. What error are you attempting to avoid? The `On Error` statement is still in effect after execution falls through, which means if an error happens in the bottom part, you're in an infinite goto-loop.

Comment: Please help me have a look at the error handling statement. There must be something wrong with it. If I change the error handling to On Error Resume Next, then it works (Excel can respond now).

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` doesn't "work", it just takes any run-time error and pretends it never happened - and that can never be a good thing when scoped to a whole function like this.

Comment: I just tried to ask the loop to move to the next one if there is an error. That is the purpose of using the on error goto statement

Comment: Imagine if `totalWT` was equal to zero at the last line of code.  You'd get a div/0 error and your error handler would send execution back up to NextJ because of your `Resume` statement.  So it runs through everything again but `totalWT` is still zero so you get an error .... And on... And on...

Comment: The point is that you're likely using error handling in place of normal flow control. If you're getting an error reading a cell, the solution isn't to just jump around: the solution is to make certain operations conditional to certain specific conditions being true or false, like that possible division by zero @ProfoundlyOblivious just mentioned: don't do the division if you know you'll be dividing by zero in the first place.

Comment: If you want a band-aid solution, add `On Error GoTo ErrHandler2` after the `If Err[.Number <> 0] Then Resume NextJ`, and add an `ErrHandler2` somewhere underneath the bottom part. If you want an *actual* solution, remove all `On Error` statements and tell us what's blowing up.

Comment: So how can I fix the error handing for the loop? Indeed, it seems that there is an infinite loop going on if error occurs.

Comment: "remove all On Error statements and tell us what's blowing up"

Comment: I removed On Error statement and now the function returned #VALUE! in Excel.

Comment: I suggest you take some steps to learn how to debug. You can't fix something of this complexity with shots in the dark, you need to understand what's going on. So you need to basically step through your code and work out why it's failing. Your problem definition is very non specific: "completely dead" whereas computer code is **very** specific, so find specifically what the problem is by stepping through the code.

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely facing an infinite goto-loop caused by faulty error handling, because the only `On Error` statement in the procedure is still in effect when execution blows up in the bottom part of the code.

Band-aid solution:

```
ErrorHandler:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Resume NextJ

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

surpL = WorksheetFunction.Percentile(a, pctL)
surpH = WorksheetFunction.Percentile(a, pctH)

total = 0: totalWT = 0
For j = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    totalWT = totalWT + b(j)
    If a(j) < surpL Then
        total = total + surpL * b(j)
    ElseIf a(j) > surpH Then
        total = total + surpH * b(j)
    Else
        total = total + a(j) * b(j)
    End If
Next j
SurpAvg = total / totalWT
ErrHandler:
End Function
```

That's bad, because we're not even bothering to *try* to figure out what's wrong, because it's substituting proper flow control for error handling. If there's a logic bug (e.g. the error we're ignoring is some *subscript out of range* error), then such error handling is *preventing* the bug from being surfaced, and makes debugging much harder than it needs to be.

A *real* solution would involve *avoiding the need to handle errors in the first place*. For example by eliminating assumptions:

```
If totalWT <> 0 Then SurpAvg = total / totalWT
```

When you use `On Error GoTo {label}`, you should write your code in such a way that `{label}` can only ever be reached while in an error state:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    '...
    Exit Sub '<~ end of "happy path"
ErrHandler: '<~ begin "error path"
    '...
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Sir. Now I implemented the If totalWT <> 0 statement. In addition, I added the statement On Error GoTo 0 below the original error handing statement If Err Then Resume NextJ. Do you think this will work?

Comment: It depends if the error causing the infinite loop was a division by zero... many other things could possibly go wrong, that's just one of them.

Comment: Anything taken from a worksheet could be a `Variant/Error`; that would be a *type mismatch*

Comment: I now added On Error GoTo 0 after the block:

Next j
ErrorHandler:
If Err Then Resume NextJ    
On Error GoTo 0

Besides, I added a statement in the end to avoid the divided by 0 error:

    If totalWT <> 0 Then SurpAvg = total / totalWT

With these two changes, is the error handling procedure OK now?

Answer (score 0):

*I put this here because it was too long for a comment and though* **I am only parroting what @Mathieu Guindon repeatedly suggested**, *it is worth repeating if it gets you on the right track.*

---

*I understand why you want good error handling but you are fixating on the wrong aspect. You can't have good error handling if you don't have a good handle on your errors.*

---

**Think about what it means to**

> [...] *eliminate assumptions* [... and ...] *make operations conditional to certain specific conditions* [...]

**and how that helps you**

> [...] *figure out what's wrong* [...]

**because**

> [...] *substituting proper flow control for error handling* [...]

**is the main problem**

> [...] *preventing the bug from being surfaced, and makes debugging much harder than it needs to be.*

---

I narrowed your code down to focus on one variable.  Look at it and see if you can find any assumptions that are not eliminated before your handler takes control, any operations that are not done under specific conditions, and if your code identifies or prevents anything that is wrong.

```
Function SurpAvg([...])
    Dim surpx As Variant
    [...]
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    [...]
        surpx = .Transpose(Range("surpx").Value)
    [...]
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    For j = LBound(surpx) To UBound(surpx)
        [...]
    NextJ:
    Next j
    ErrorHandler:
    If Err Then Resume NextJ
    [...]
    End Function
```

---

The only assumptions I see eliminated are the ones eliminated be the  default handler.   Control is given to your handler without any preconditions, even the workbook is assumed with `ThisWorkbook.Activate`. The assumption is that the `ActiveWorkbook` is not calling outside code.  If it is called by outside code, something commonly done with Personal.xlsb or an *.xlam add-in, then you will be working with the wrong workbook; consider 'Workbook1'Sheet1!A1 contains a UDF hosted in Personal, using `ThisWorkbook` means the function returns a value derived from data in Personal and not from data in 'Workbook1'Sheet1!A1

Take a close look at: `surpx = .Transpose(Range("surpx").Value)`  This line is executed before control is assigned to your error handler, so an error here is handled by the default handler; but it can't catch logic errors and you may have an error here that is syntactically correct but still causes a run time error further in the code or perhaps cause an inaccurate result.  For example:

- `Range("surpx")` is not explicitly qualified.  The named range
  `surpx` can be scoped to a workbook and any number of individual
  worksheets inside it.  Your code assumes the active sheet is the
  correct sheet and it will happily take unexpected values but at least the
  default handler will alert you with an Error 1004 message if the
  range does not exist.
- `Range("surpx").Value` is blindly accepted and used without
  preconditions.  I am fond of `div/0` errors, so consider what happens with one in that
  range. `surpx` is a `Variant` so it happily takes the value of "Error
  2007" without any issue until you try using it with `For j = LBound(surpx) To UBound(surpx)`. This is the first line of code after
  you've given authority to your handler so the default handler cannot help you and there is literally no
  attempt to prevent, correct, or provide information that identifies
  the error. The only thing your handler does is silently skip a block of
  code.  This is the antithesis of good error handling.

My advice, beyond what has already been said, revisit your data types to remove the variants, really think about how this code is called, explicitly qualify your objects, and even though this has been said, it is worth repeating again, **use the default handler to debug the program before you enable a custom handler**.